# XNA curve import from Maya?

Tags: xna, maya, fbx

I am trying to import a movement curve from Maya into my XNA game, but I cannot figure out how. Basically I want to catch the curve by it's name, and look up its values at different points of time.

Are curves exported into FBX at all? And, if not, then how to catch it?

Edit: Maya can export to Maya ASCII, and I tried to parse it, but I am not sure what formula I should use to recreate the curve.

Here is a Maya ASCII segment defining a typical curve:

```
createNode transform -name "curve1";
createNode nurbsCurve -name "curveShape1" -parent "curve1";
    setAttr -keyable off ".visibility";
    setAttr ".cached" -type "nurbsCurve" 
        3 11 0 no 3
        16 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 11 11
        14
        -4.9774564508407968 0 -6.8331005825440476
        -5.5957526204336077 0 -5.5944567905896161
        -6.8323449596191823 0 -3.1171692066807277
        -5.6935230034445992 0 3.3047128765440847
        -1.6528787527978079 0 8.8676235621397499
        7.5595909161095838 0 10.325347443191644
        9.2297347448508607 0 8.5586791722955731
        10.0730315036276 0 0.93412333819133941
        5.9770106513247976 0 3.7809964481624871
        2.9006817236214149 0 -3.3327711853359037
        11.373191256465434 0 -4.6672854260704906
        4.5697574985247682 0 -14.178349348937205
        2.4191279569332935 0 -11.415532638650156
        1.3438131861375628 0 -10.034124283506653
        ;
```

I managed to find the file format reference somewhere, the important info here is the knot indexes (`16 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 11 11`) and the coordinates (all lines containing three numbers).

But, I still have no idea how to recreate the curve. I googled a lot for nurbscurves, bsplines etc, but could not successfully match the result in Maya with any code I could find.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this in 3dsmax by exporting the curve in Ascii format and parsing the text manually, does Maya have any such exporter?

Comment: It can save to Maya Ascii. I already made a parser for it, but I have been unable to recreate the correct path this way, the format is too complex. I was hoping XNA can import the FBX and give access to the curve this way.

Comment: I edited the original post, and added some info about the way Maya ASCII defines a curve.

Comment: @sinsro Yeah I can see how that would be difficult to recreate! XNA models curves as rational Bézier splines rather than nurbs afaik. How realistic would it be to create your curves as bézier splines rather than nurbs in Maya? (I've never used Maya myself unfortunately)

Comment: The problem is I need to recreate the exact mathematical formula, even the slightest inaccuracy makes the animations look noticeably off. I tried some approximations, and it just did not work visually. So, hopefully someone here can help...

Comment: No solution so far, I'm considering just making my own WYSIWYG path editor in the game engine instead, using a regular spline path.